# jQuery show element ID only on homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this jQuery code on my site

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("mysite.com/") != -1){
$("#announcer_box").hide();
```

I would like to show this element ID on my homepage,but exclude it from all other pages. how is this possible?

i am using wordpress.

Comment: I don't understand.  It looks like that's what that jquery is trying to do.  I guess if it's not showing up you could do an `else { $("#announcer_box").show(); }`...also, that's not a "CSS ID" that's just the element ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
if ((window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/") != (window.location.href)) {
        $("#announcer_box").hide();
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

On your home page, give the `<html>` or `<body>` tag a special class (like maybe "homepage"):

```
<html class='homepage'> <!-- plus any other classes you want/need -->
```

Then in your CSS:

```
#announcer_box { display: none; }
.homepage #announcer_box { display: block; }
```

Comment: @Pointy I am using wordpress and it is one of the plugin i am trying to modify so i cant play with the css

Comment: @rockydude there's no way to add your own CSS on top of what the plugin involves? That seems unlikely, but Wordpress never fails to underwhelm me :)

Answer (score 0):

you might have a `<body class="homepage">`, then, something like that ?

```
if($("body").hasClass("home")
  $("#announcer_box").hide();
```

Comment: @user2829210 I am using wordpress and it is one of the plugin i am trying to modify so i cant play with the css